# How do I remove the horizontal scrollbar in a div?

Tags: html, css, overflow, horizontal-scrolling

When I set `overflow: scroll`, I get horizontal and vertical scrollbars.

Is there a way to remove the horizontal scrollbar in a div?

Answer (score 260):

```
overflow-x: hidden;
```

Comment: it's a bad solution. Because in this case you just hide horizontal scroll in container. But if this container is too wide your content will not be fit in your container.

Answer (score 66):

Don't forget to write `overflow-x: hidden;`

The code should be:

```
overflow-y: scroll;
overflow-x: hidden;
```

Answer (score 27):

#### CSS

```
overflow-y: scroll;
```

[See it on jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/alexdickson/94Wh7/).

Notice if you remove the `-y` from the `overflow-y` property, the horizontal scroll bar is shown.

Answer (score 23):

With `overflow-y: scroll`, the vertical scrollbar will always be there even if it is not needed. If you want y-scrollbar to be visible only when it is needed, I found this works:

```
.mydivclass {overflow-x: hidden; overflow-y: auto;}
```

Answer (score 22):

To hide the horizontal scrollbar, we can just select the scrollbar of the required div and set it to `display: none;`

**One thing to note is that this will only work for WebKit-based browsers (like Chrome) as there is no such option available for Mozilla.**

In order to select the scrollbar, use `::-webkit-scrollbar`

So the final code will be like this:

```
div::-webkit-scrollbar {
  display: none;
}
```

Answer (score 21):

Add this code to your CSS. It will disable the horizontal scrollbar.

```
html, body {
    max-width: 100%;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

Answer (score 20):

Removes the HORIZONTAL scrollbar while ALLOWING for scroll and NOTHING more.

```
&::-webkit-scrollbar:horizontal {
  height: 0;
  width: 0;
  display: none;
}

&::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:horizontal {
  display: none;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for apparently being the only person on the internet accurately answering this lol! Nice one

Answer (score 19):

No scroll (without specifying x or y):

```
.your-class {
   overflow: hidden;
}
```

Remove horizontal scroll:

```
.your-class {
   overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

Remove vertical scroll:

```
.your-class {
   overflow-y: hidden;
}
```

Comment: OP needs scrolling without scrollbar

Answer (score 9):

To remove the horizontal scroll bar, use the following code. It 100% works.

```
html, body {
    overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

Answer (score 6):

If you don't have anything overflowing horizontally, you can also just use

```
overflow: auto;
```

and it will only show scrollbars when needed.

See *[The CSS Overflow Property](http://css-tricks.com/the-css-overflow-property/)*

Answer (score 6):

```
overflow-x:hidden;
```

However, it may happen that your content on the website may not show. So best to inspect element and check the widths of your divs or sections, and remove any right/left margins it may have put in extra. Much better solution

Answer (score 2):

Use:

```
overflow: auto;
```

This will show the vertical scrollbar and only if there is a vertical overflow, otherwise, it will be hidden.

If you have both an x and y overflow, then both x and y scrollbars will be shown.

To hide the x (horizontal) scrollbar, even if present simply add:

```
overflow-x: hidden;
```

```css
body {
    font-family: sans-serif;
}

.nowrap {
    white-space: nowrap;
}

.container {
    height: 200px;
    width: 300px;
    padding 10px;
    border: 1px solid #444;

    overflow: auto;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<ul>
  <li>Item 1</li>
  <li>Item 2</li>
  <li>Item 3</li>
  <li>Item 4</li>
  <li>Item 5</li>
  <li>Item 6</li>
  <li>Item 7</li>
  <li class="nowrap">Item 8 and some really long text to make it overflow horizontally.</li>
  <li>Item 9</li>
  <li>Item 10</li>
  <li>Item 11</li>
  <li>Item 12</li>
  <li>Item 13</li>
  <li>Item 14</li>
  <li>Item 15</li>
  <li>Item 16</li>
  <li>Item 17</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

To hide the `scrollbar`, but keep the behaviour.

```
div::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 0px;
  background: transparent;
}
```

---

**There are limitations to this.**

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::-webkit-scrollbar

Answer (score 1):

Use This chunk of code..

```
.card::-webkit-scrollbar {
  display: none;
}
```

Comment: This does remove both scrollbars (y and x). Still a good indication though

Answer (score 0):

### Hide Scrollbars

### step 1:

go to any browser for example Google Chrome

 click on keyboard ctrl+Shift+i inspect use open tools Developer

### step 2:

Focused mouse on the div and change style div
use try this:

```
 overflow: hidden; /* Hide scrollbars */
```

now go to add file .css in project and include file

Answer (score 0):

lastly i encountered this issue the overflow-x property did not help me and i think its a banal solution, i recommend to inspect and check the elements that are potentially big and take more size than the other elements in your page, don't forget to check the width of some of your container the width based on view (vw) property can restrict your containers and its so practical.
good luck.

Answer (score -2):

I had been having issues where I was using

```
overflow: none;
```

But I knew CSS didn't really like it and it didn’t work 100% for how I wanted it to.

However, this is a perfect solution as none of my content is supposed to be larger than intended and this has fixed the issue I had.

```
overflow: auto;
```