# How to get rid of this scrollbar?

Tags: css

From my example here:
http://www.singaporeswimming.com.sg/button-problem
I want to get rid of the horizontal scrollbar, but unable to do so.

I can easily use overflow-x: hidden, but I do not want to touch the css of the modal plugin. I only want to change elements from the source.

Any idea?

Comment: i dont see any scrollbar???

Comment: oh i do now, ill have a look for you

Answer (score 1):

Check this Question - [remove horizontal scrollbar in div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4405954/remove-horizontal-scrollbar-in-div) the answer is the same as the one of @Connor Miles
As a besides note - use the full power of CSS (*Cascading* Style Sheets by adding your styles in external files. It's very hard to debug right now.

Answer (score 0):

Add `overflow-x:hidde`n; top the body of the register page that is displaying in lightbox, this way your not touching the lightbox