# How to get rid of horizontal scroll of a page

Tags: html, css, viewport, horizontal-scrolling

I'm making a landing and I've this set of rules applied for the body and html elements:

```
html {
   margin: 0px;
   height: 100%;
   width: 100%;
}

body {
   margin: 0px;
   min-height: 100%;
   width: 100%;
}
```

Also, everything is viewported:

```
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

And on the picture, below, you can see main blocks of the page, they all have width 100%

[image: the pics]

However, nothing of what I mentioned really helped and the blocks of the page despite they all have 100% width, have different size and, there's a horizontal scrollbar too.

What should I do to get rid of the scrollbar and to make all the blocks be the size of a current viewport?

Comment: Can you set up a live example somewhere, maybe a jsfiddle.net?

Comment: of the whole page?

Comment: Ideally, yes. There may be a shortcut though - does any of your 100% wide elements have padding? Remove it, the padding gets added to the 100%

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to remove the horizontal scrollbar in a div?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4405954/how-to-remove-the-horizontal-scrollbar-in-a-div)

Comment: have you tried setting overflow-x: hidden ?

Comment: What you show doesn't show the problem, as far as the markup goes. You did the right thing by posting your markup here but we can't duplicate the problem with that.

Comment: I've removed the paddings and tried the overflow thingy. Paddings helped, but there's still some scroll

Answer (score 6, accepted):

try put

```
overflow-x: hidden;
overflow-y: scroll;
```

at the body {

Comment: set my answer as helpful please

Comment: I'll, it doesn't want to accept it unless few mins are gone

Comment: while this might work, this work as quick fix/hack, would be preferable, if you show your code to have a proper answer to your problem

Comment: Where should I show it? my css is written in less. Should I just post it on fiddle?

Comment: Also, I didn't have box-sizing, I just looked it up, I forgot to put it, so It added up to the issues too. Now, since I used border-box, the content looks neater

Answer (score 3):

you shouldn't have horizontal scrollbar. If you have horizontal scrollbar - one of the elements overflow the main page. Try to find which makes the problem.
If you use overflow - you don't correct the problem, but cover it.
It will blow when you scale the page - the content won't be center.

Comment: I removed the overscroll and it was fine, after I added the boxing-size. I think, it was prob the issue, somewhere margin or padding came out of the page

Comment: It is good to check paddings and margins in developer tools in browser, and in case it happen - remove paddings/margins.

Answer (score 0):

Delete `width: 100%;` from body and html.

Comment: if there's no width:100%; , the browser will set it to default width , and the default width is 100% , this make no diffrent

Comment: If so there is an error somewhere else in the code.. The horizontal scrolling is not normal.