# Horizontal scroll bar in all broswers

Tags: html, css

I'm learning HTML,CSS .A basic step toward web development, so here's a small project got from school I'm working on !,
A horizontal  scroll bar is displaying without any reason !

```html
<html>
<head>
 <title>Home</title>
 <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="bootstrap.min.css" />
 <script type="text/javascript" src="bootstrap.min.js"></script> 

</head>
<body>
   <div class="row" style="background : #f5eef8">

       <div class="col-md-8 ">

          <img src="logo.png" height= "85px" width="300px">

        </div>

        <div  style="margin-top:  30px ;" class="col-md-4 " >
          <a style="color: #3b5998  ; " type="button" class="btn-lg  " href="https://facebook.com">  <i  class="fa fa-facebook"></i></a>
          <a style="color:  #0084b4; " type="button" class="btn-lg  " href="https://twitter.com">  <i  class="fa fa-twitter"></i></a>
          <a style="color:  #3F729B; " type="button" class="btn-lg  " href="https://instagram.com">  <i class="fa fa-instagram"></i></a>
          <a style="color:   #DD4B39; " type="button" class="btn-lg  " href="https://google.com">  <i class="fa fa-google"></i></a>
          <a style="color:  #CB2027; " type="button" class="btn-lg  " href="https://pinterest.com">  <i class="fa fa-pinterest"></i></a>
       </div>

    </div>

    



</body>
</html>
```

Comment: First of all put your row in a container . Do you want to remove horizontal scroll ?

Comment: Please see this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4405954/how-to-remove-the-horizontal-scrollbar-in-a-div

Comment: Thank you for now I just fixed it By using below mention code !

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to remove the horizontal scrollbar in a div?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4405954/how-to-remove-the-horizontal-scrollbar-in-a-div)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't want a horizontal scroll bar do this

```
<style>    
    body {
        overflow-y: hidden;
    }
</style>
```

Comment: Ok, But why its happening?

Comment: I am not sure, for my browser the horizontal scrolling bar does not appear.

Comment: @irfanadil have you checked it in different browsers ?

Comment: Yes I've checked it was displaying in all browsers !