# prevent the horizonatal scrolling bar from showing up

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to have a trapezoid shape In my website, everything is Ok I got the shape but I got a weird behaviour with it which is this horizontal scrolling bar:

[image]

I know where it come from it's when I set the height of the `div` that will be the trapezoid

this is my code:

```css
.trapezoid {
  clip-path: polygon(0 32%, 100% 0, 100% 100%, 0 70%);
  background-color: #33cccc;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50vh;
  position: relative;
  max-width: 95vw;
}
```

```html
<div class="trapezoid">
  <div class="circle">

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You can just add `overflow-x: hidden` to the `body`; although I'd recommend looking into what's causing the overflow in the first place and fix it to avoid it :)

Comment: that's the point I don't know how to fix this problem it's caused when I increase the height of the div more than 10vh

Comment: Your vertical scrollbar comes into the picture at some point while resizing. The vertical scrollbar itself has its own width that's now on your page and eats into the horizontal real estate. Your trapezoid then start overflowing horizontally because its width is 100% of the page but the visible page width has reduced to something like 97% due the vertical scrollbar. This causes the horizontal scrollbar to show up. If you can, try to prevent the vertical scrollbar from coming up in the first place and it should look ok. Otherwise you'll have to use overflow-x: hidden

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add this to the div that is making the horizontal scroll, or to the body:

```
overflow-x: hidden;
```

[See more here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4405954/how-to-remove-the-horizontal-scrollbar-in-a-div)

Comment: Just remember that you cannot use position: sticky on a child then.