# How to adjust 100vh height with horizontal scrollbar?

Tags: html, css

I want a `div` of `height` and `width` both equal to `100% of browser window`. I want the scrollbars to only show when `min-height` or `min-width` comes into consideration.

```css
body {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  margin: 0;
}

#root {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  min-height: 800px;
  min-width: 600px;
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Page Title</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="root"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

My problem is that suppose `width` becomes less than `min-width`, both scrollbars (horizontal and vertical) show up, even if `height` is more than `min-height`. I want that vertical scrollbar should not show up. I want that height of `#root` should become `100vh - horizontalScrollbarHeight`. How to do that?

Comment: Use with media-query - https://stackoverflow.com/q/4405954/7427111

Answer (score 0):

If I am understanding correctly, what you basically want is a scrolling window within your page and that you only want it to show up when the window is above a certain size. See my pen at [this link](https://codepen.io/hmcka/pen/mdbYKrB). [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overflow-x#Examples) was my reference.

```css
body {
  margin: 10;
  background: black;
}

#root {
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
  overflow-x: auto;
  overflow-y: auto;
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Page Title</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="root">
    <p>When you add much more text than the size of the window, the scroll bars will appear. </p>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: actually, I only want to show scrollbars when window is **below** certain size. I want `#root` to be of 100% of body, that is where the problem is